# Convert an ASCII coded string to normal String - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an ASCII character string and I need to convert it to a normal string.

```js
var asciiString = '84114117116104326510811997121115328710511011532'

function strFunc(str) {
    var result = []

    var strSplit = str.split('');

    var validAscii = ['32'];
    for(var i=65; i<=90; i++) {
        validAscii.push(i.toString());
    }
    for(var i=97; i<=122; i++) {
        validAscii.push(i.toString());
    }
    strSplit.forEach((item, index) => {
        if(validAscii.includes(parseInt(item))) {
            result.push(item)
        } else if (validAscii.includes(`${parseInt(strSplit[index])}${parseInt(strSplit[index + 1])}`)){
            result.push(item)
        }
    })
    return result.fromCharCodeAt(...result)
}

console.log(strFunc(asciiString))
```

Why does it return an empty string? I need to split the string into either 2 digit or 3 digits and compare it with the array I built.

The string should be split as [84, 114, 117, 116, 104, 32, 65, ...] which translates to **TRUTH A....**
Please advice.

Comment: If it starts with 1, it’s 3 digits. If it doesn’t, it’s 2 digits. Repeat.

Comment: What is a "normal" string?

Comment: Why don't you put delimiters in the ASCII string so you can just split it that way?

Comment: *"Why does it return an empty string?"* Because you are comparing numbers against strings. `[42].includes('42')` is `false`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey After we convert an ascii character to text. In this case we need to split the string as [84, 114, 117, 116, 104, 32, 65, ...] which translates to TRUTH A...

Comment: @FelixKling I changed it to an array of numbers now and still same.

Comment: It's not the same, the string returned is non-empty. FWIW, `validAscii.includes(parseInt(item)` is never `true` because now your checking whether a number is in an array of strings, and because `item` is always a single digit whereas `validAscii` contains data with at least 2 digits. Also calling `parseInt` in `${parseInt(strSplit[index])}` is unncessary since you are converting the value back to a string again.

Comment: `fromCharCodeAt` is not an array method. Did you read the documentation? Maybe you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode ?

Comment: What should happen if a 2 or 3 digit character sequence is not one if your `validAscii` entries (e.g. 27)? Should it be ignored?

Comment: Agreeing with @Barmar and proposing the other common methods, convert the ASCII bytes to two-digit hexadecimal, or convert the ASCII bytes to Base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this way

```js
const encodedString = '84114117116104326510811997121115328710511011532';
const codes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < encodedString.length;) {
  const numDigits = encodedString[i] === '1' ? 3 : 2;
  codes.push(encodedString.substr(i, numDigits));
  i += numDigits;
}
const str = String.fromCharCode(...codes);
console.log(`"${str}"`);
```

Some notes:

- It assume values in the encoded string go from 32 to 127. There's no error checking
- There's no reason to call `parseInt` as JavaScript will convert numbers strings to numbers so passing the numbers as strings to `String.fromCharCode` works.

As for why your code doesn't work, a couple of issues include

1. it's looping over every character, not every code.

   It's looping over 8, 4, 1, 1, 4, ... instead of 84, 114, ...

   This means neither test will pass since `item` will never be something found in `validAscii` which means `result` will have nothing pushed to it.
2. There's no function `Array.fromCharCodeAt`

   `result` is an array and there is no such function as `array.fromCharCodeAt`.  If result had the correct codes in it then you could use `String.fromCharCode(...result)`

Answer (score 1):

When you're combining two elements of the string, you need to call `parseInt()` *on the result of the concatenation, not concatenate the results of `parseInt()`. So it should be:

```
} else if (validAscii.includes(parseInt(item + strSplit[index+1]))){
```

And since ASCII values can be 3 digits, you need another `else if` that looks for `item + strSplit[index+1] + strSplit[index+2]`.

Another problem is that you're pushing `item` onto the result string. But to get the corresponding character, you need to use `String.fromCharCode()` to convert the concatenated ASCII code to a character.

```js
strSplit.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (validAscii.includes(parseInt(item))) {
    result.push(String.fromCharCode(item))
  } else if (validAscii.includes(parseInt(item + strSplit[index+1]))) {
    result.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(item + strSplit[index+1]))
  } else if (validAscii.includes(parseInt(item + strSplit[index+1] + strSplit[index+2]))) {
    result.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(item + strSplit[index+1] + strSplit[index+2]))
  }
})
```

Note that using `forEach` like this is probably not a good idea. If there are overlapping items in the input that are both in `validAscii`, you'll add both of them to the result. E.g. if it contains `678` you'll match both `67` and 78`, and add the corresponding characters to the result. Instead, you should use an ordinary`for` loop, and increment the index by the number of characters that you matched.

Comment: The first condition is never true, is it?

Comment: Probably not, but I left it in for completeness in case he adds some single-digit values to `validAscii`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `parseInt` around the templated string, not the individual items. You were checking if the string is included in an array filled with numbers.

```js
var asciiString = '84114117116104326510811997121115328710511011532'

function strFunc(str) {
    var result = []

    var strSplit = str.split('');

    var validAscii = [32];
    for(var i=65; i<=90; i++) {
        validAscii.push(i);
    }
    for(var i=97; i<=122; i++) {
        validAscii.push(i);
    }
    strSplit.forEach((item, index) => {
        if(validAscii.includes(parseInt(item))) {
            result.push(item)
        } else if (validAscii.includes(parseInt(`${(strSplit[index])}${(strSplit[index + 1])}`))){
        
            result.push(item);
        }
    })
    return result.join('');
}

console.log(strFunc(asciiString))
```